# Initialize not properly make with classes vb.net

Tags: vb.net

So, I need to do an program for a client and he wants a search bar in it.  So I made it and everything worked perfectly but I put it in my main form.  Now, I want to put it in a class but when I initialize the program, it gives me the following error

```
An error occurred while creating the form. For more information, 
see Exception.InnerException. The error is: The form is self-reference during
construction from a default instance, which led to infinite recursion. In the
constructor of the form, refer to the form using 'Me'.
```

I tried to put Me.Rbtn_X... but it doesn't recognize it.

**Initialization**

```
' Main form
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Initialize_search()
End Sub
```

**Initialize_search()**

```
' Main form
' search is initialize like this :
' Dim search as New Research
Private Sub Initialize_search()
    search.generate_autocomplete()
End Sub
```

**generate_autocomplete()**

```
' Research class
Sub generate_autocomplete()  
    ' Main_form = Main form  
    Dim field = ""
    ' This is the place where the program fail
    If Main_form.RbtnR_avancee_contact.Checked Then
        field = "personneressource"
    Else
        field = "beneficiaire"
    End if
    ' ....
End Sub
```

Is there something I didn't understand or It's not possible to do it that way?

**Edit: added Form_shown event**

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Initialize_search()
End Sub

Private Sub Form_personne_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    MessageBox.Show("You are in the Form.Shown event.")
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, forget to remove it.. It doesn't create any problems because it's not related to the Research class

Comment: NO!  Leave `InitializeComponent()` in Sub New and take ALL your code out and put it in FormShown.   You cannot "initialize" other stuff before the form creates those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is not created (fully) until New completes.  By adding your `Initialize_search` to it, it eventually leads to the statement `Main_form.RbtnR_avancee_contact.Checked'.  This is wrong on two counts:

1) the form doesnt exist yet, so you cant refer to it. (this is what the error meant with 'form is self-reference during construction')

2) the ref should be Me.RbtnR (which is what it meant by 'refer to the form using 'Me'')

Move your `Initialize_search` to the `Form_shown` event.  Your code should look like this (including Lar's suggestion)

```
' Main form
Public Sub New()
    ' REQUIRED
    InitializeComponent()

End Sub
```

If there is really something that needs to be setup for this, add it to the form_shown event:

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
      Handles Me.Shown
      ' NOTE: even .NET refers to ME not MainForm etc

     InitializePanel 
     InitializeSeach

End Sub
```

Then:

```
Private Sub Initialize_search()
    search.generate_autocomplete(Me.RbtnR_avancee_contact.Checked)
End Sub
```

Then:

```
Sub generate_autocomplete(AdvContact as Boolean)  

    Dim field AS STRING = "" 

    If AdvContact  Then
        field = "personneressource"
    Else
        field = "beneficiaire"
    End if
   ' ....
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that but the program just don't start at all. Even if I only put an MessageBox inside the event

Comment: Yes, it drills down to 'generate_autocomplete' which will be referencing the form before it is created, AND refers to it incorrectly.

Comment: @Marc-AndréTrahan you put a msgbox inside WHAT event there are dozens.  BTW, BOTH changes are required.  How does the program start by form or Sub Main?

Comment: In Project Properties, is THIS form the startup form or a different form (or Sub Main).  If this is not the main form, how are you creating and showing it (code, please)

Comment: Yes, this is my startup form

Comment: did you leave `InitializeComponent()' in sub new?  that is required for the form to startup.  Just YOUR code was supposed to be moved.

Comment: I edited the question and added the code of the Form_shown event

Answer (score 1):

Your `search` class doesn't have a reference to the instance of the form's controls.

Try passing the value instead:

```
Sub generate_autocomplete(advancedChecked As Boolean) 
  Dim field As String = ""
  If advancedChecked Then
    field = "personneressource"
  Else
    field = "beneficiaire"
  End if
End Sub
```

Then when you call it:

```
search.generate_autocomplete(Me.RbtnR_avancee_contact.Checked)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if did work like you want it to, according to your code, it would always result in `field` containing the same value (whichever was set in designer).

Instead, try putting this code inside `RbtnR_avancee_contact.Checked` event. Or even TextChanged for the autocomplete box (and initialize it for the first time user enters anything), it would examine the checked state and populate autocomplete items.

With this approach, if your user never uses the search box, you don't need to initialize it.